# Binary encoding in data processing

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to do binary encoding of income column of a dataframe which has two categories "<=50k" and ">50k" as 0 and 1 respectively. How should I do that?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please check [ask] and provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create boolean mask and convert to integers - `True`s are `1`s and `False`s are `0`s:

```
df['binary'] = (df['col'] > 50000).astype(int)
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(423)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randint(100000, size=1000)})


In [30]: %timeit df['income']=df['col'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>50000 else 0)
762 µs ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit df['binary'] = (df['col'] > 50000).astype(int)
357 µs ± 4.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit df["income"] = np.where(df["col"] <50000, 0, 1)
375 µs ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "apply":

```
df['income']=df['income'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>50000 else 0)
```

Edit 1:

I think this would be much faster than my previous answer:

```
df["income"] = np.where(df["col"] <50000, 0, 1)
```

Performance:

```
%timeit df["income"] = np.where(df["col"] <50000, 0, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 256 µs per loop

%timeit df['income']=df['col'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>50000 else 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 477 µs per loop

%timeit df['binary'] = (df['col'] > 50000).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
```

Comment: `apply` are loops under the hood, so it is slowier like vectorized solution with converting boolena mask to integers.

Comment: It is better, but if want add timings add all 3 solutions, because it depends of computer